# Having trouble comparing a Java string with a line from a txt file

Tags: java, file

This method is supposed to add a song's information to a txt file, but first it needs to check if a song with the same name and artist already exists.

```
static void addSong(Song song){
        Boolean SongAlreadyExists = true;

        // variable is to compare if song already exists char by char up to artist
        String lineToAdd = "NAME:" + song.name + "|ARTIST:" + song.artist;
        
        try {
            FileReader fReader = new FileReader("songs.txt");
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);
            String line;             

            while((line = bReader.readLine()) != null){
                for (int i=0; i < lineToAdd.length(); i++){
                    if (line.charAt(i) != lineToAdd.charAt(i)){
                        SongAlreadyExists = false;
                        System.out.println("variable changed");
                    }
                }
            }
            bReader.close();
            fReader.close();

        } catch (IOException exception){
            System.out.println("file not found");
        }

        //add song to the text file with all songs if song doesnt exist        
        if (! (SongAlreadyExists)){
           System.out.println("Adding song");
            try {
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("songs.txt", true);
                fileWriter.write("\nNAME:" + song.name + "|ARTIST:" + song.artist + "|ALBUM:" + song.album + "|YEAR:" + song.year + "|");
                fileWriter.close();
            } catch (Exception exception){
                System.out.println("error");
            }
        }
```

And this is the data in the txt file using the same data from the object I am testing

```
NAME:TestName|ARTIST:TestArtist|ALBUM:TestAlbum|YEAR:2005|
```

For some reason I keep running the code with the same test song object and it keeps saying that a duplicate does not exist, but in the text file I clearly see the duplicates being added. In the console, the "variable changed" keeps getting outputted multiple times every time even though it is the same test object being used. How can I check if the information of an object is already stored in a txt file?

Comment: Could you try adding System.out.println("Position:" + i + " Line '" + line.charAt(i) + "' LineToAdd '" + lineToAdd.charAt(i) + "'");  above the "variable changed"?

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock Thank you, using that console log actually helped me find the error. My approach for this method was bad because after each line of the txt file got scanned it would check if that individual line is the duplicate, and if it was, it would still move on to check to the next line. Then since the next line was not a duplicate, the SongAlreadyExists variable was changed to false, completely disregarding the previous lines.

Comment: Watch your [naming](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)
- your code is hard to read as a result